# Is there a slicer that can set the print speed for each layer as a function of the layer area?

Tags: slicing, speed

Is there a slicer that can set the print speed for each layer as a function of the layer area? Larger areas give the layer a longer time to cool off before the next print layer.  When the layer areas start to get small (usually at toward the end of a print if so) the layer may need a slower speed to cool off.

Comment: Most slicers have a feature in their cooling settings to "slow down if layer print time is below xxx".
Setting this to a higher value should ensure that small / short layers aren't printed too fast, so that cooling is still reliable.

Shorter layers are slows down linearly to reach the specified minimum time - unless a "minimum print speed" is also set.

Comment: @lowe Found this setting.  This does what I'm after.

Comment: @lowe yes, all I needed to do was increase the default layer time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most slicers have a feature in their cooling settings to "slow down if layer print time is below xxx".

Setting this to a higher value should ensure that small / short layers aren't printed too fast, so that cooling is still reliable.

Shorter layers are slowed down linearly to reach the specified minimum time - unless a "minimum print speed" is also set.